# Draw line with gradient

Tags: android, canvas, line

I have multiple lines draw in different positions.
For example:

```
canvas.drawLine(startXLine1 ,stopXLine1, startYLine1, stopYLine1, paint)
canvas.drawLine(startXLine2 ,stopXLine2, startYLine2, stopYLine2, paint)
```

I want a gradient like this for each line:
[image]

When I try this, I don't have this effect, but the gradient with this direction  blue(left) ---> white(right)
Like this: http://media.24ways.org/2011/verou/1.png

```
Shader shader = new LinearGradient(startXLine1, startYLine1, stopXLine1, stopYLine1, res.getColor(R.color.blue),  res.getColor(R.color.white), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

paint.setShader(shader);
```

Someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fill the background like in your image:

```
Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, h /*canvas height*/, res.getColor(R.color.blue),  res.getColor(R.color.white), Shader.TileMode.MIRROR /*or REPEAT*/);

paint.setShader(shader);
```

Comment: It still with wrong direction. I want blue on top and white on bottom, and I get blue on left and white on right

Comment: I've edited the answer, try again with the updated suggestion please. Let me know :)

Comment: The direction is equal

Comment: This works for me. Check that `h` is not zero, or post what you are passing as coords.