# MpAndroidChart (or another iOS/Swift chart tool) use gradient based on 3rd variable

Tags: ios, swift, charts, mpandroidchart

In matlab I can iterate through data points and plot each line segment with a colormap based on a 3rd variable [see image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icZkx.jpg)

Is there a way to do this in MpAndroidChart (or another tool usable in iOS)?

So far, I'm able to create a LineChartDataSet for each point with a programmatic color, but then it doesn't render the lines (as each data set is independent). This would allow me to create a scatter chart with circles that have a color/heat map but not a line chart.

[image: Example gradient based on 3rd variable]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the sdk code to draw gradient lines.
Take line chart for example, the line is drawn by LineChartRenderer, in function drawLinear, and colour is set by mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j));
So, change this line to your own gradient colour then the line is gradient.
the result likes this and gif diff is append after picture:
[image]

code change like  this:

```
diff --git a/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java b/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java
index 5ee04e2e..cee10568 100644
--- a/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java
+++ b/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java
@@ -3,8 +3,10 @@ package com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Color;
+import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
 import android.graphics.Paint;
 import android.graphics.Path;
+import android.graphics.Shader;
 import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
 
 import com.github.mikephil.charting.animation.ChartAnimator;
@@ -370,7 +372,9 @@ public class LineChartRenderer extends LineRadarRenderer {
                     continue;
 
                 // get the color that is set for this line-segment
-                mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j));
+                //mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor(j));
+                Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 200 , Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
+                mRenderPaint.setShader(shader);
 
                 canvas.drawLines(mLineBuffer, 0, pointsPerEntryPair * 2, mRenderPaint);
             }
@@ -413,7 +417,9 @@ public class LineChartRenderer extends LineRadarRenderer {
 
                     final int size = Math.max((mXBounds.range + 1) * pointsPerEntryPair, pointsPerEntryPair) * 2;
 
-                    mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor());
+                    //mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor());
+                    Shader shader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 200, 200 , Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
+                    mRenderPaint.setShader(shader);
 
                     canvas.drawLines(mLineBuffer, 0, size, mRenderPaint);
                 }
```

gradient line by  [Draw line with gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28029006/draw-line-with-gradient)